# SQL query to get all addresses associated with customer in Magento

Tags: mysql, magento, magento-1.6

I'm migrating from Magento, and need the mySQL query to get all addresses associated with each customer.

this is how I get the address IDs, but not sure if customer_address_entity.parent_id is a customer id.

```
select 
    email, group_concat(a.entity_id)
from
    customer_entity as c
        inner join
    customer_address_entity as a ON a.parent_id = c.entity_id
group by email
```

My Magento DB dump is from Magento 1.6.x

Can you propose a query for it?

Comment: common guys, it is just one query. what paragraphs are you talking about?

Comment: Nice, all you who voted against are 0 in magento topic. I would propose Stackowerflow to not allow vote negatively for those who has no reputation on tags that are assigned to question.

Answer (score 4):

Better SQL then above.. will auto get IDs.. just need to pass entity Type ID where 1 = customer Entity Type and 2 = customer address entity type.. additionally could find those 2 values out via code

```
$customerTypeID = Mage::getModel('eav/entity')->setType('customer')->getTypeId();
$customerAddressTypeID = Mage::getModel('eav/entity')->setType('customer_address')->getTypeId();
```

AND BELOW SQL :

```
SELECT
email,
a.entity_id AS addressId,
IF(def_billing_address.value = a.entity_id,1,0) AS isDefaultBillingAddress,
IF(def_shipping_address.value = a.entity_id,1,0) AS isDefaultSippingAddress,
addr_firstname.value AS firstname,
addr_lastname.value AS lastname,
addr_street.value AS street,
addr_city.value AS city,
addr_region_code.code AS stateCode,
addr_region.value AS state,
addr_zipcode.value AS postalCode,
addr_country.value AS countryCode,
addr_telephone.value AS telephone
FROM mg_customer_entity AS c
INNER JOIN mg_customer_address_entity AS a ON a.parent_id = c.entity_id

LEFT JOIN mg_customer_entity_int AS def_billing_address ON
    (def_billing_address.entity_id = c.entity_id) AND
    (def_billing_address.attribute_id = (SELECT attribute_id FROM mg_eav_attribute AS eav WHERE eav.attribute_code = 'default_billing' and eav.entity_type_id = 1))
LEFT JOIN mg_customer_entity_int AS def_shipping_address ON
    (def_shipping_address.entity_id = c.entity_id) AND
    (def_shipping_address.attribute_id = (SELECT attribute_id FROM mg_eav_attribute AS eav WHERE eav.attribute_code = 'default_shipping' and eav.entity_type_id = 1))
LEFT JOIN mg_customer_address_entity_varchar AS addr_zipcode ON
    a.entity_id = addr_zipcode.entity_id AND
    addr_zipcode.attribute_id = (SELECT attribute_id FROM mg_eav_attribute AS eav WHERE eav.attribute_code = 'postcode' and eav.entity_type_id = 2)
LEFT JOIN mg_customer_address_entity_varchar AS addr_city ON
    a.entity_id = addr_city.entity_id AND
    addr_city.attribute_id = (SELECT attribute_id FROM mg_eav_attribute AS eav WHERE eav.attribute_code = 'city' and eav.entity_type_id = 2)
LEFT JOIN mg_customer_address_entity_varchar AS addr_country ON
    a.entity_id = addr_country.entity_id AND
    addr_country.attribute_id = (SELECT attribute_id FROM mg_eav_attribute AS eav WHERE eav.attribute_code = 'country_id' and eav.entity_type_id = 2)
LEFT JOIN mg_customer_address_entity_varchar AS addr_firstname ON
    a.entity_id = addr_firstname.entity_id AND
    addr_firstname.attribute_id = (SELECT attribute_id FROM mg_eav_attribute AS eav WHERE eav.attribute_code = 'firstname' and eav.entity_type_id = 2)
LEFT JOIN mg_customer_address_entity_varchar AS addr_lastname ON
    a.entity_id = addr_lastname.entity_id AND
    addr_lastname.attribute_id = (SELECT attribute_id FROM mg_eav_attribute AS eav WHERE eav.attribute_code = 'lastname' and eav.entity_type_id = 2)
LEFT JOIN mg_customer_address_entity_text AS addr_street ON
    a.entity_id = addr_street.entity_id AND
    addr_street.attribute_id = (SELECT attribute_id FROM mg_eav_attribute AS eav WHERE eav.attribute_code = 'street' and eav.entity_type_id = 2)
LEFT JOIN mg_customer_address_entity_varchar AS addr_telephone ON
    a.entity_id = addr_telephone.entity_id AND
    addr_telephone.attribute_id = (SELECT attribute_id FROM mg_eav_attribute AS eav WHERE eav.attribute_code = 'telephone' and eav.entity_type_id = 2)
LEFT JOIN mg_customer_address_entity_varchar AS addr_region ON
    a.entity_id = addr_region.entity_id AND
    addr_region.attribute_id = (SELECT attribute_id FROM mg_eav_attribute AS eav WHERE eav.attribute_code = 'region' and eav.entity_type_id = 2)
LEFT JOIN mg_customer_address_entity_int AS addr_region_id ON
    a.entity_id = addr_region_id.entity_id AND
    addr_region_id.attribute_id = (SELECT attribute_id FROM mg_eav_attribute AS eav WHERE eav.attribute_code = 'region_id' and eav.entity_type_id = 2)
LEFT JOIN mg_directory_country_region AS addr_region_code ON
    addr_region_id.value = addr_region_code.region_id
```

Answer (score 0):

I found it. Just check if in your database the `entity_id` is the same as in my example.

In my dump they are:

```
city=15, country_id=11, firstname=9, lastname=10, postcode=14, street=16, telephone=17, region=12,region_id=13
```

And here is the query which worked for me.

```
SELECT
    email,
    a.entity_id AS addressId,
    IF(def_billing_address.value = a.entity_id,1,0) AS isDefaultBillingAddress,
    IF(def_shipping_address.value = a.entity_id,1,0) AS isDefaultSippingAddress,
    addr_street.value AS street,
    addr_city.value AS city,
    addr_region_code.code AS stateCode,
    addr_region.value AS state,
    addr_zipcode.value AS postalCode,
    addr_country.value AS countryCode

FROM
    customer_entity AS c
        INNER JOIN
    customer_address_entity AS a ON a.parent_id = c.entity_id

-- DEFAULT BILLING ADDRESS - 7
-- DEFAULT SHIPPING ADDRESS - 8
-- city=15, country_id=11, firstname=9, lastname=10, postcode=14, street=16, telephone=17, region=12,region_id=13
LEFT JOIN customer_entity_int AS def_billing_address ON
  (def_billing_address.entity_id = c.entity_id) AND
  (def_billing_address.attribute_id = 7)
LEFT JOIN customer_entity_int AS def_shipping_address ON
  (def_shipping_address.entity_id = c.entity_id) AND
  (def_shipping_address.attribute_id = 8)
LEFT JOIN customer_address_entity_varchar AS addr_zipcode ON
    a.entity_id = addr_zipcode.entity_id AND
    addr_zipcode.attribute_id = 14
LEFT JOIN customer_address_entity_varchar AS addr_city ON
    a.entity_id = addr_city.entity_id AND
    addr_city.attribute_id = 15
LEFT JOIN customer_address_entity_varchar AS addr_country ON
    a.entity_id = addr_country.entity_id AND
    addr_country.attribute_id = 11
LEFT JOIN customer_address_entity_varchar AS addr_firstname ON
    a.entity_id = addr_firstname.entity_id AND
    addr_firstname.attribute_id = 9
LEFT JOIN customer_address_entity_varchar AS addr_lastname ON
    a.entity_id = addr_lastname.entity_id AND
    addr_lastname.attribute_id = 10
LEFT JOIN customer_address_entity_text AS addr_street ON
    a.entity_id = addr_street.entity_id AND
    addr_street.attribute_id = 16
LEFT JOIN customer_address_entity_varchar AS addr_telephone ON
    a.entity_id = addr_telephone.entity_id AND
    addr_telephone.attribute_id = 17
LEFT JOIN customer_address_entity_varchar AS addr_region ON
    a.entity_id = addr_region.entity_id AND
    addr_region.attribute_id = 12
LEFT JOIN customer_address_entity_int AS addr_region_id ON
    a.entity_id = addr_region_id.entity_id AND
    addr_region_id.attribute_id = 13
LEFT JOIN directory_country_region AS addr_region_code ON
    addr_region_id.value = addr_region_code.region_id
```

Comment: The logic is there, but with so much ids, we need to get them automatically based on the attribute_code